# Music distortion from a Bluetooth board at high volume levels

Tags: amplifier, audio, distortion

I have a Drok Bluetooth audio amplifier board that comprised of a [TPA3116](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpa3116d2.pdf) audio amplifier, a JL Bluetooth receiver and processing IC and a couple of RLC circuits. I've noticed that when I turn up the volume all the way the music gets distorted, so I connected the audio out to an oscilloscope to see if it could give me some insight on the problem. The audio signal seems to get cut off when the amplitude of the audio signal surpasses the supply voltage. I have tried increasing the supply voltage to see if that would change the output, but it did not. Why does this distortion happen? 
[image]

Comment: Without a schematic (and probably board layout) this may be very difficult or impossible.

Comment: Basically, you're clipping. Because your volume is too high..."An over-driven signal causes the amplifier to attempt to produce an output voltage beyond its capability, which is when clipping occurs."

Comment: Wait...are you driving a speaker? If yes, what impedance?

Comment: @NatsuKage I've driven speakers with 6 Ohm and 8 Ohm impedances. It has a left and right output so I usually drive a speaker on one side and my oscilloscope on the other.

Comment: I'd check if the audio input voltage is too high perhaps at max volume. Maybe a bad design for the audio between the amp and the bluetooth chip?